# Using a string value as a generic type parameter

Tags: c#, .net, system.reflection

Let's say I have a method that looks like this:

```cs
public bool Execute<T>()
 {
 }
```

...and I have a string variable that describes the class name of the type I need to pass in, like

```cs
string typeName = "Person"
```

I've naively tried

```
var typeDef = Type.GetType(typeName);
 Execute<typeDef>();
```

, but that's a no-go. Is there a programatic way of passing in a generic type parameter when all I have is the class name in a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var typeDef = Type.GetType(typeName);
var ret = (bool)this.GetType().GetMethod(nameof(Execute)).MakeGenericMethod(typeDef).Invoke(this, new object[0])
```